# How to install and run Versi Design Template for Marklogic?

Tags: xquery, marklogic

Can someone tell me how to install and run Versi Design Template for Marklogic ? I followed the instructions given in the getting started guide but it is giving me errors. Versi design template is available at the following link:-

```
http://community.marklogic.com/code/versi
```

Comment: Can you explain what errors are you getting?

Answer (score 0):

To my knowledge, the Versi project exists quite long already. Not sure how well it has been kept up to date. If you are thinking about using it to develop web applications more quickly, you might also be interested in RunDMC, which is more actively maintained for sure:

http://community.marklogic.com/code/rundmc

HTH!

Comment: grtjn is correct - this project has not been well maintained.  RunDMC might be helpful wrt code samples and the like.  It uses MarkLogic XSLT support to turn templates, content in the database, and other configuration into the developer.marklogic.com (DMC) website.